# Query table by string matching without using LIKE?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I query a table where first name starts with 'N' and last name starts with 'K' **without using** `like`?

Comment: Why would you not want to use `like`? It is the only solution that doesn't obfuscate its meaning to future maintainers of your code.

Comment: @Rob, `like` is a very common semantic, but calling it *the only* semantic probably goes a bridge to far.  The substring and between N & O answers below are perfectly readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE SUBSTR(firstName, 1, 1) = 'N'
AND   SUBSTR(lastName,  1, 1) = 'K';
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [regular Expression](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/oracle/regexp.html) ?

```
select * from table1 where regexp_like ( firstName, '^N*');
select * from table1 where regexp_like ( lastName, '^K*');
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try with > and < operators

e.g.:

WHERE NAME >= 'N' AND NAME < 'O'

but I don't guarantee you get each and every letter you would expect (especially with accentuated characters if any)

Scal